# In Kivy, how can I animate a series of widgets with a loop?

Tags: python, animation, kivy

I am writing an app in which I've run into a situation where I would like to animate a series of objects sequentially by iterating through a for loop.

When I run the app and click the button, I want the first label's text to shrink, wait for a 1.5s pause, the second label to shrink, wait, shrink, wait, shrink, etc. However, when it's run, though the app sleeps for each of the 1.5 seconds, none of the animations occur until after the for loop has run it's course, and then they all run at once.

I've pared the problem code out of my main code below and the issue still persists. Does anyone have a solution or an alternative? I suspect it has something to do with multithreading, but that's just a guess. I've tried decorating **shrinkray** with @mainthread, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import time

class Test(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.thislabel1 = Label(text="One")
        self.add_widget(self.thislabel1)
        self.thislabel2 = Label(text="Two")
        self.add_widget(self.thislabel2)
        self.thislabel3 = Label(text="Three")
        self.add_widget(self.thislabel3)
        self.thislabel4 = Label(text="Four")
        self.add_widget(self.thislabel4)
        self.thislabel5 = Label(text='Five')
        self.add_widget(self.thislabel5)
        self.button1 = Button(text='Shrink Ray')
        self.button1.bind(on_release=self.shrinkray)
        self.add_widget(self.button1)
        self.these_children = [self.thislabel1,self.thislabel2,self.thislabel3,self.thislabel4,self.thislabel5]

    def shrinkray(self,*args):
        anim = Animation(font_size=1)
        for these_labels in self.these_children:
            anim.start(these_labels)
            time.sleep(1.5)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you need **multithreading** for this. Because your main kivy loop gets affected when you loop and use `time.sleep()` in the main thread. However, for you example, you only need one extra `thread` to run the loop as the following (follow the comments):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import time
import threading

class Test(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.thislabel1 = Label(text="One")
        self.add_widget(self.thislabel1)
        self.thislabel2 = Label(text="Two")
        self.add_widget(self.thislabel2)
        self.thislabel3 = Label(text="Three")
        self.add_widget(self.thislabel3)
        self.thislabel4 = Label(text="Four")
        self.add_widget(self.thislabel4)
        self.thislabel5 = Label(text='Five')
        self.add_widget(self.thislabel5)
        self.button1 = Button(text='Shrink Ray')
        self.button1.bind(on_release=self.shrinkstart)  # here the button targets the thread starter function
        self.add_widget(self.button1)
        self.these_children = [self.thislabel1,self.thislabel2,self.thislabel3,self.thislabel4,self.thislabel5]

    def shrinkstart(self, *args):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.shrinkray)  # initiate the thread
        t.daemon = True  # daemon thread so it terminates when stopping the main thread
        t.start()  

    def shrinkray(self):
        anim = Animation(font_size=1)
        for these_labels in self.these_children:
            anim.start(these_labels)
            time.sleep(1.5)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks a lot for the fast input. I'll start delving into the docs on threading so I can get a better grasp on this